# AWS Route53 SSL communication failure: Received fatal alert

Tags: protocols, amazon-route53, communication, health-check

I have one site deployed on AWS Rosa. This site is secured with https protocol. I am trying to create Route53 healthcheck for that site. The Route53 healthcheck fails stating reason -
**Failure: Resolved IP: x.x.x.x. SSL communication failure: Received fatal alert: protocol_version**

However I am able to access the site on browser.
As mentioned at-
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-fix-unhealthy-health-checks/

following curl command returns me httpcode 200 and response time less than 1 second

```
curl -Ik -w "HTTPCode=%{http_code} TotalTime=%{time_total}\n" <http/https>://<domain-name/ip address>:<port>/<path> -so /dev/null
```

---

Also when I was trying to run same command with old curl version, I was getting error -
**routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version**

The error from Route53 also shows protocol version. Not sure if these 2 are related.

Anyone came across this issues , any pointers will be highly appreciated.

If site URL is accessible over browser, then Route53 health check should return healthy state